# How to read parameters from URL in a specific way with express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, get

I created a server with the **express** package, and I'm trying to read in a       specific way the parameters from the URL.
The URL goes like this: http://127.0.0.1:8080/screen=3 **(no '?' as the sign for parameters).**
I need to save the number of the screen in a variable.

---

I tried this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/screen:sceenNum', function (req, res) {
    var temp = req.sceenNum;
    res.send(temp); //for checking on the browser
});
```

I also tried this, but he must get '?' in the URL:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var screenNum = req.param('screen');
    res.send(screenNum);
});
```

Can anyone please have a solution?
Thank you

Comment: the question mark is how query string parameters work? why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access route/url parameters with the `req.params` object.

So a route like `/screen:screenNum` would accept urls like `/screen3` and you would access `3` via `req.params.screenNum`.

Similarly, if you want to use the equals, just add that: `/screen=:screenNum` and the number is accessed the same.